# Extracting rows in a loop using a range of time

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27, 30),
                   Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15))

Time  Value
 1     1
 3     2
 4     3
 6     4
 7     5
10     6
11     7
12     8
16     9
19    10
21    11
23    12
26    13
27    14
30    15
```

Now, for every 5 seconds in the Time variable, I would like to extract/filter all the values for the first 2 seconds (and get rid of the last 3 seconds) as such:

```
Time Value
 1     1
 6     4
 7     5
 11    7
 12    8
 16    9
 21    11
 26    13
 27    14
```

I think the code would use `for loops` to look something like this:

```
for(every 2 seconds in Time variable){
     new_data <- filter(the first 2 seconds) 
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you provide the expected result? What did you try?

Comment: @Waldi, I've edited my question to make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
n <- 5
first <- 2

data[(data$Time-1)%%n<first,]

   Time Value
1     1     1
4     6     4
5     7     5
7    11     7
8    12     8
9    16     9
11   21    11
13   26    13
14   27    14
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(inFive = ceiling(Time/5)) %>%
  group_by(inFive) %>%
  filter(Time %% 5 %in% 1:2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-inFive)

# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#    Time Value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     6     4
# 3     7     5
# 4    11     7
# 5    12     8
# 6    16     9
# 7    21    11
# 8    26    13
# 9    27    14
```